# In Jquery, How to increment Animation-Delay Time for each Child of the element selected?

Tags: auto-increment

"Rectangle" is the class of list of elements. I would like to add Animation class with some regular intervals using Animate-delay: 
Seems it's not working!! Here my jQuery code:

```
 var element = $('.rectangle');
 for (var i = element.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    element[i].css('animation-delay',i+'s').addClass('animated fadeInRight'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an Easy Solutions for the above question.

```
    var current = 0;
    $( ".rectangle" ).each(function(){
      $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight').css('animation-delay', current+'s');
      current++;
    });
```